# Masonry Bootstrap Columns(4) not all used unless minimum 6 items exist

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

http://www.bootply.com/brOEODSopK#

When running this code in bootply, it appears everything works perfect. If you reduce the testimonials down to 5 or less, all data is pushed into columns 1 and 2, ignoring column 3 and 4 until 6 or more testimonials exist. Is it possible to fix this? If I have 3 testimonials, it should spread across 3 columns. If I have 4 it should spread across the 4.

Please advise

Comment: Are you new to bootstrap?

Comment: I've been making use of it the last year. So, kinda new I guess.

Comment: See if this seems okay:http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/XpGWNX

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the divs will not auto arrange as they do in the original code.  This solution is creating rows for every 3, which is static. And the items should stack just below one another in their respective columns. The original code works perfect, with 1 exception. When there around less then 6 items, it does not utilize all columns. Since the data will vary, as I am pulling it from a database, I need this to be able to work with as little as 1 item or as many as 50.

Answer (score 0):

CODE: http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/XpGWNX

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container testimonials-parent">
  <h1>Masonry CSS with Bootstrap</h1>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="item col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Fun : My son enjoys it. It did surprise me when it went from adding to “less than” and “greater than.”</p>
                    <footer>Dayna from United States about GS Kids! Preschool Numbers (Windows Store) on Sep 29, 2014</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-4  col-lg-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Happy daughter and happy parents : Not glitchy, very encouraging for children, rewarding, entertaining, and best of all its educational. My daughter is transitioning between pre-k skills to kindergarten and this as well as other GS apps seem perfect. Will be upgrading.</p>
                    <footer>Robertson from United States about GS Kids! Preschool Numbers (Windows Store) on Sep 09, 2014</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Wow app : Great app for kids to learn and fancy their imagination.</p>
                    <footer>Ramanjit from India about GS Kids Paint &amp; Learn (Windows Store) on July 19, 2014</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="row">
            <div class="item col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Love : we love coloring. Its great for us!!!</p>
                    <footer>Alfredo from United States about GS Kids Paint &amp; Learn (Windows Store) on Feb 05, 2014</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>My girls’ go to game : This is the app my 3yo picks every time she’s allowed on my computer. Sometimes the “crayon” will get stuck, but overall, it’s been a great app for her and her big sisters.</p>
                    <footer>Sandy from United States about GS Kids Paint &amp; Learn (Windows Store) on Feb 14, 2014</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="item col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Good for learning Alphabets : My son is enjoying painting and learning Alphabets.</p>
                    <footer>Sulabha from India about GS Kids Paint &amp; Learn (Windows Store) on July 29, 2014</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
  </div>

</div>



testimonials-parent, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.testimonials-parent .row {

 -moz-column-gap: 1em;/* Firefox */
 -webkit-column-gap:1em;/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 column-gap:1em;  
}



blockquote {
    border-left: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    background-color: #00cccc;
}

blockquote p{
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-style:oblique;
    font-size: 1.125em;
}

blockquote footer{
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}

blockquote p:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Aakash Thakur proposed the same solution but this does not fix the problem, as it creates a new one. The data can vary, as it comes from a database. So at times we may have 1 record or as many as 50. The items should stack just below one another in their respective columns. Using the code above, its basically hard coding each row. Which prevents the ability to stack properly.